# How to use conditional class and class with variable with ngClass in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

There is two classes should be applied to the same div:

```
<div [ngClass]="['class_01_'+someVar, {'class_02': isSelected}]><div>
```

I get the error:

```
Error: NgClass can only toggle CSS classes expressed as strings, got [object Object]
```

How to use conditional class and class with variable with ngClass in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't really do it with `ngClass` alone given what you're trying to do. You'll need to do it with separate `ngClass` and `class` directives like:

```
<div [ngClass]="'class_01_'+someVar" [class.class_02]="isSelected"><div>
```

Comment: ```<div class="class_01_{{ someVar }}" [ngClass]="{class_02: isSelected}"></div>```
It also should work.